# Xamarin Ui Test IApp C# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, testing

I am new using Xamarin UI Test and I am trying test a app developed by other company.

In my first .cs I am using a if to identify a condition and start my tests. So condition identified my test goes to another class and... fail.

I receive a error message "Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object". When I go to line/.cs I see this line: "app.Query("Welcome to").Any();".

And in the new class I have "IApp app" with a green line below with the message "(field) IApp ZZZZZZZ.app

Field 'ZZZZZZZ.app" is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null."

I don't know how to continue my tests using "IApp app" in another .cs without using AppInitializer every time.

Any tips?

Comment: I suggest you reading this and following tutorial there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/
You clearly must have done something wrong. Also to create a UITest you can actually select Xamarin UITest from the list when you add new Project test. That would populate majority of your settings up code. The only thing you will have to do is literally change the IPA and APK locations.

Comment: Hello.
Thank you for trying help me. 
But I think you don't understood my question.
I followed the tutorial and read the documentation. If I run the tests in a single class I know how to use the IApp and it will running fine. But if I have diferent classes I don't know how to use the IApp in the other class.
I don't know to instanciet the IApp in diferent classes.